# can not get output of shell script's echo to a Java variable

Tags: java, shell, echo, output

I am calling a shell script with Java, in the shell script I am running some queries and getting their running times,(e.g. when I save echo TIME's result in an output file, I get e.g. 28sec 27sec 34sec in one column) however I can not get the output of echo TIME to a Java,when running the program I am getting some weird decimal numbers. My code for getting the output from shell script is this:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Test
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          TreeMap <String, Long> myMap = new TreeMap <String, Long>();
          String output = "";
          String line = "";

          myMap.put("key", value);
          myMap.put("key", value);

          List<String> cmdList = new ArrayList<String>();
          cmdList.add("/path/to/the/test/file/test.sh");
          for(Map.Entry entry : myMap.entrySet())
          {
             cmdList.add(entry.getKey().toString());
             cmdList.add(entry.getValue().toString());

          }
          try
          {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdList.toArray(new String[cmdList.size()]));
            //get input stream of the process
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
             output += line;
            } 
          }
          catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage()); }

      System.out.println(output);
     }

 }
```

My shell script looks something like this:

```
    i=0
    args=("$@")
    while [ $i -lt $# ]
    do
    START=`date +%s`
       some operation here
    END=`date +%s`
    echo $END - $START | bc
    done
```

Weird output from java:

```
    A   F   37734107.00 56586554400.73  53758257134.8700    55909065222.827692  25.522006   38273.129735    0.049985    1478493N    991417.00   1487504710.38   1413082168.0541 1469649223.194375   25.516472   38284.467761    0.050093    38854N  O
```

What I might be doing wrong in my code?

Comment: You should at least: a) show us how you run the script (the part you show us tells almost nothing) b) the scripts output when run in command line c) output from your java program

Comment: In addition, be sure to identify what the script is printing to stdout vs stderr.

Comment: Can you add the script's output when you run it in the command line?

Comment: @Ingo I put it above, those numbers are the ones I get in the command line

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand. You said, this is the java output. What exactly is "weird"?

Comment: @Ingo I thought I will get an output from echo $END - $START. When I put the result in a text file as echo $END - $START>>output.txt, I did get the right result:28 and 28 in seconds, i.e. running time for two queries. I was hoping to get those results in the command line, but it didn't happen

Comment: Wouldn't you have to get the process's OUTPUT stream rather than its INPUT stream?

Comment: @MarkSetchell because I'm trying to read the output of the shell script

Comment: @MarkSetchell or am I confusing the two?

Comment: I don't know - I am no Java expert. But as it is a class of the process, I would have thought you might want the process's output. Try it. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: @Ingo I am executing mysql database queries, maybe that's the reason I get such output in a command line?

Comment: The problem with you is that you won't see the difference between: a) the output of your java program b) the output of your shell script. And yet, a depends on b, so if we do not know how b looks we can't say that a is "weird".

Comment: @Ingo I can only get an output of a shell script in a file when I call the script from Java, but if I don't indicate the file, I don't get the output. And I don't know how to run the script by itself in order to get its output, as it needs to be supplied with arguments, which must be supplied by Java program. I tried running it by itself but it does nothing.

Comment: @user3344382 you could print the command line you generate in your java, and then use copy and paste to runthe thing